# Using filter to determine if all via foreign key connected Objects to an Object have property

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i am trying to get "All People that possess only books they have read".

i have models like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id =      Integerfield(primary_key=True)
class Book(models.Model):
    id =      Integerfield(primary_key=True)
    owner =   ForeignKey("Person")
    is_read = BooleanField()
```

Now i am trying to filter with

```
Person.objects.filter(book__is_read=True)
```

but i need something like

```
Person.objects.filter(for_all__book__is_read=True)
```

Is there a way to achive this in Django?

**Edit:**
I am now using DRF to get the data from the model, so i used serializers to get my Json Data.
So it looks something like this now:

```
class SerializerBook(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Auftraege
        fields = ["id","owner","is_read"]

class SerializerPerson(ModelSerializer):
    book= SerializerBook(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Probanden
        fields = ["id","book"]
```

I thought that now, when the data is grouped up nicely, its easier to filter. So i could do something like

```
...
person=Person.objects.all().values("id","book__id","book__is_read")
serializer=SerializerPerson(person,many=True)
for person in serializer.data:
     read_all_books=True
     for book in person.book:
          if(book.is_read==False):
                 read_all_books=False
                 break
     if(read_all_books==False):
          del(person)
return (serializer.data)
```

(haven't tested it, just to illustrate what i need)
Now i really would prefere, if i could use the database to do the filtering, instead of python. Is there any way to get to this result with only database-side filtering?

Comment: First you need to change up your model a little bit there is no need to create and ID field. if you want to get all the books related to person object that is_read=True you can use reverse relation to fetch them and get the is_read=True

Comment: i just made up that example and included the IDs for clarity. Otherwise the Person model would be empty :D.